# Why does scrollTop has a fractional part?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to scroll down a div with a lot of data when I press play on a video.

I get this weird issue where my scrollTop is `211.25` but my `scrollHeight` is `711` and clientHeight is `500px`

I had to put a `Math.floor` on scrollTop to get it to an even number.

Where is this `.25px` coming from?

HTML:

```
<video id="v0" tabindex="0" autobuffer="autobuffer" preload="preload" controls>
  <source src="http://res.cloudinary.com/david-wash-blog/video/upload/sample-video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
  <p>Sorry, your browser does not support the &lt;video&gt; element.</p>
</video> 
<div id="data-scroll">
   SOME DATA
   SOME DATA
   SOME DATA
   SOME DATA
   SOME DATA
   SOME DATA

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#v0 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#data-scroll {
  width: 500px; 
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  border: solid red 10px;
}
#footer {
  height: 400px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
(function(){
  var vid = document.getElementById('v0'); 
  var dataScroll = document.getElementById('data-scroll');
  var controls = document.getElementById('controls');


  function playScroll(){
      console.log(`clientHeight:${dataScroll.clientHeight}`);
      console.log(`scrollHeight: ${dataScroll.scrollHeight}`);
      console.log(`scrolling dataScroll @ ${dataScroll.scrollTop}`);
      script.scrollTop += 100;
      if(dataScroll.scrollHeight - Math.floor(dataScroll.scrollTop) === script.clientHeight){
        console.log(`stop scrolling dataScroll @ ${dataScroll.scrollTop}`);
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(playScroll);
      }
      window.requestAnimationFrame(playScroll);
    }

  vid.addEventListener('play', function(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(playScroll);
  });
}());
```

Comment: I think that's where the browser thinks the scroll top is. Partial pixel values are quite normal.

Comment: I have no padding though or anything. I don't see where it gets a `.25px` from. I don't know how the browser assumes it's a .25px

Comment: Well, we can't tell what's happening in your specific situation, because the code is incomplete, but imagine you have an image that is 400 px wide and 300 px high, but it is displayed with a width of 525.0 pixels, then the height would become 393.75 pixels. That affects all content blocks below it. Inspect the page, and you will probably find something like this.

Comment: ahh okay that makes sense I'll check using wed dev tools to get exact heights of the inner elements, I tried it earlier but on the data itself and not the parent object

Comment: According to the specs, "On systems using display scaling, scrollTop may give you a decimal value."  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Comment: yeah, I saw that but what is display scaling? Is that responsive design? Is that for smaller values? I don't understand what they mean by display scaling here.

Comment: I assume "display scaling" means setting a scale other than 100% for the display, e.g. https://images.idgesg.net/images/article/2018/07/scalingwindows10-100764460-large.jpg - but why are you testing for equality rather than that `scrollTop >= scrollHeight - clientHeight` anyway?

Comment: `scrollTop >= scrollHeight - clientHeight` does not always work, because sometimes the comparison ends up somethin like `100.75 >= 101`, and because 100.75 was not rounded up to 101 (and the scrollTop value will never be higher than 100.75 in the example) the check fails. In my testing, `Math.round(scrollTop) >= scrollHeight - clientHeight` seems to always do the trick so far in the cases I've had. I keep wondering why people design APIs the way they do... Oh, let's just round this one, but not that one, skippity doo.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does scrollTop has a fractional part?

Because web spec authors felt like it for some odd random reason, literally.

Most likely what you're looking for is this:

```
// It reached the bottom.
Math.round(scrollTop) >= scrollHeight - clientHeight
```

So far that has been working for me. I don't know of anything better yet, but if I find out, I'll update it.

EDIT: The previous one doesn't always work. Sometimes `scrollTop` will be slightly more or less than `scrollHeight - clientHeight` after rounding, especially in cases when content is scaled (f.e. zoom or CSS transforms).

This is what I'm using now, working well, with `Math.abs` to handle the more-or-less case:

```js
function isScrolledToBottom(el) {
    // NOTE: scrollTop is fractional, while scrollHeight and clientHeight are
    // not, so without this Math.abs() trick then sometimes the result won't
    // work because scrollTop may not be exactly equal to el.scrollHeight -
    // el.clientHeight when scrolled to the bottom.
    return Math.abs(el.scrollHeight - el.clientHeight - el.scrollTop) < 1
}
```

Note, I'm not using `window` APIs, only element APIs because this works in every scroll case, including for the top level scroll of the page.

For top level scroll, we can use it like this:

```js
isScrolledToBottom(document.documentElement)
```

but we can also use it for scroll within any element nested anywhere in the page.

Comment: haha I'm not even in this codebase anymore but thanks love to see some answers and solutions to learn from!